# Signal-to-Noise Ratio (SNR) needed to discern two superimposed signals

Tags: homework, noise

Say I am trying to measure a exponentially decaying signal ($S_y$), that constitutes a portion $\gamma$ (about 5% so $\gamma=\frac{1}{20}$) of total signal measured($S=S_y+S_b$ and $S_b=S_0 \beta e^{\frac{-t}{C_b}}$ and $S_y=S_0 \gamma e^{\frac{-t}{C_y}}$). Where $\gamma+\beta=1$ and $C_Y$ is about $\frac{1}{4}$ of $C_b$. I want to determine the least Signal-to-Noise Ratio (SNR) needed to be able to discern that signal. The noise in our signal is additive white noise. Should the SNR be $>\gamma=\frac{1}{20}$ or is there a better more formal way to decide the SNR limit? $$S(t)=S_0(\gamma e^{\frac{-t}{C_y}}+\beta e^{\frac{-t}{C_b}}) + n(t)$$

So my question is `how` do I determine the minimal SNR when I measure signal $S$ over time $t$, but the thing I am interested in is fluctuation (max 10%) in $S_y$. All constants are known to me, however i only know the mean of $C_y$, as it fluctuates and so $S_y$ does too. Thanks for any help. If I need to clarify any details please tell me and I will do so.

Comment: Do you know anything about the noise in your signal? Is it Gaussian? White? Additive? Multiplicative?

Comment: Do you mean: $S(t)=S_0(\frac{1}{20}e^{\frac{-t}{C_y}} + \frac{19}{20}e^{\frac{-t}{C_x}})$ (i.e. $+$ rather than multiply) ?

Comment: @Jason: Its white noise

Comment: @Peter: Indeed you are right, I meant +.

I will correct my original post for both Peters and Jasons comments. thanks

Comment: Another question, this stackexchange is not very populated. I have used stackoverflow and mathematics.stackexchange before, which were much more helpful. Do you think I can post this question on either one of those? They both already have SNR questions. Although stackoverflow has implementing and coding questions about SNR so I guess mathematics would be better.

Comment: Leo, I think this is probably the best place to ask... If you want to ask it elsewhere on the *.SE network, please do not cross-post it. Work with us (me and the other mods here) to migrate it where you think it might be more appropriate.

Comment: Just looking at this again:  What are you actually trying to measure? Is it $C_y$? Or something else? Do you know $C_x$, or does that have to be estimated too? To ask the question a different way: What is "unknown" here? It's not clear (to me).

Comment: I am trying to measure $S_y$ which is $\frac{1}{20}$ of the signal. I measure signal $S$ over time $t$ and all constants are known to me. However I need to be able to measure fluctuations in $S_y$ so my SNR needs to be low enough. My question is how to determine the appropriate SNR to be able to measure differences in $S_y$, which constitutes 5% of $S$. A rough estimate of fluctuation in $S_y$ is about 10%.

Comment: OK Just saw this now, after entering my response (I got distracted with other stuff). Will ponder this and update later...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a work-in-progress until more information is added to the question.

First, I'm assuming that you know the magnitudes of your decaying exponentials, but you don't know their time constants (either $C_x$ or $C_y$) or your signal level $S_0$.

Second, you say that there is Gaussian noise, but not whether it's additive. I'm going to assume it's additive. That means your signal is really:

$$
S(t)=S_0(\frac{1}{20}e^{\frac{-t}{C_y}}+\frac{19}{20}e^{\frac{-t}{C_x}}) + n(t)
$$

where $n(t)$ is additive, white, Gaussian noise with zero mean and variance $\sigma^2$.

Then, to set up the problem, we need to postulate the estimated values of $\hat{C}_x$, $\hat{C}_y$, $\hat{S}_0$, and $\sigma^2$ in $\hat{S}(t)$:

$$
\hat{S}(t; \hat{C}_x, \hat{C}_y, \hat{S}_0)=\hat{S}_0(\frac{1}{20}e^{\frac{-t}{\hat{C}_y}}+\frac{19}{20}e^{\frac{-t}{\hat{C}_x}})
$$

Then a least squares approach to solving it would define the error, $E$, as:

$$
E(\hat{C}_x, \hat{C}_y, \hat{S}_0) = \int_{I} \left| S(t) - \hat{S(t)}\right|^2 dt
$$

where $I$ is your time interval of interest, and minimize this with respect to $\hat{C}_x$, $\hat{C}_y$,  and $\hat{S}_0$.

I interpret your question as asking: what value $\frac{S_0^2}{\sigma^2}$ does this work over?

The answer is: it depends on what you mean by "work".  You can get *an* estimate for any noise level.  The question is, what error can you tolerate in that estimate.  Also, it will depend somewhat on your integration length ($I$).

---

**EDIT**

OK, I see you've changed notation so it's $C_b$ and $C_y$ now.

I've written a short `scilab` script to try to see how things change with noise level. I've assumed EVERYTHING is precisely known except the $C_y$ parameter.

The error in estimating the parameter versus the value of $\sigma$ is shown in the plot below.  Code below generates it.

[image]

---

```
 S0 = 1;
 Cb = 201;
 Cy = 100;
 sigma = 0.1;
 mb = 1/20;
 my = 19/20;

 T=1000;
 t=[0:T-1];
 Sb = mb*exp(-t/Cb);
 Sy = my*exp(-t/Cy);

 clf
 subplot(311)
 plot(Sb)
 plot(Sy,'g')
 plot(S,'r')

 ERRORS = [];
 sigmaRange = [0.0 0.1 0.2 0.5 1 2 5 10];
 for sigma=sigmaRange,
 CyhatRange = 90:.01:110;
 estimates=[]
 NRuns = 100;
 for n=1:NRuns
     S = S0*(Sb + Sy) + sigma*rand(1,T,'normal');

     ERR= [];
     for Cyhat = CyhatRange,
         S_hat = S0*(Sb + my*exp(-t/Cyhat))

         ERR = [ERR; sum((S-S_hat).^2)];
     end

     [mx,ix] = min(ERR);

     CyhatEst = CyhatRange(ix);
     //disp(CyhatEst);
     estimates = [estimates; CyhatEst];

     subplot(312);
     plot(CyhatRange,ERR)
 end

 disp(mean((estimates-Cy).^2))

 ERRORS = [ERRORS; mean((estimates-Cy).^2)];
 end

 subplot(313)
 plot(sigmaRange,ERRORS);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Your assumptions on the noise are correct. I will add it to the post.

Comment: Yes sorry I added $\gamma$ and $\beta$ to make the question more generic, so I changed $C_x$ to $C_b$ to make it more readable. Wow thanks for your help. Your assumption about the parameters being known is correct. Now for how to use this: I should determine the tolerable error for my measurement and then use your explanation to decide on the SNR?

Comment: Well, based on the plot, it looks like you need to have $\sigma$ less than $1$ for $S_0 = 1$.  The error really gets big after that, and "saturates".